# My Ancestry bookmark icon just changed to a red ball f5. How do I change it back to the original default icon?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, bookmarks

Somehow every bookmark associated with Ancestry has been changed to a red ball with f5 inside of it.  I can't find this Favicon file/folder.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an old post to hit shift command R while on the bookmarked page. I think it worked! The red ball f5 has been changed back to the original green 3 leaf icon! Thanks to the original problem solver. I hope it works for you.

Comment: This answer was the simplest I could find and worked for me.  Apparently it doesn't always work.  But try it because if it does it is by far easier than most the other suggestions I looked at and or tried.